# A tricky problem about matrices with no $\{-1,0,1\}$ vector in their kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

A [Hankel matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix) is a square matrix in which each ascending skew-diagonal from left to right is constant. Let us call a matrix partial Hankel if it is the first $m<n$ rows of some $n$ by $n$ Hankel matrix. I was posed this question by a mathematician a few years ago and I have been completely stuck on it ever since.   Let us assume all our partial Hankel matrices have elements which are chosen from $\{-1,1\}$.

> Does there exist an $m$ by $n$ partial Hankel matrix $M$ such that it has $m < n/2$ rows and there is no non-zero vector $v\in\{-1,0,1\}^n$ in its kernel?

Such matrices certainly do exist for non-Hankel $m$ by $n$ $\{-1,1\}$-matrices.

Other that writing computer code to exhaustively explore small matrices I am not sure how to approach this question.

I would be very grateful for any ideas at all.

Comment: maybe counting the number of solutions for $m=1$, then for $m=2$, etc, and see if we arrive at $m = N/2$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Do you mean fix $n$ to some value and do this by computer code or try to find some closed form way? I don't know how to find a formula for the number of solutions sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears completely equivalent to ask this question for [Toeplitz matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) instead of Hankel matrices. The reason is that arranging the $m$ rows of any partial Hankel matrix simply in reverse order turns it into a rectangular Toeplitz matrix but doesn't affect its kernel. I will give an answer for Toeplitz matrices below.

In [another answer at MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207043/two-conjectures-about-zero-inner-products-and-dissociated-sets/229555#229555) I have argued that for "typical" $m$ by $n$ $\{0,1\}$-matrices $M$, regardless of whether they have Toeplitz (or circulant) form or not (in other words, they are chosen at random either among *all* $m$ by $n$ $\{0,1\}$-matrices, with uniform distribution, or within the subsets of Toeplitz or circulant matrices), the following holds:

> If $w \in \{-1,0,1\}^n$ is a random vector with i.i.d. components, distributed with probabilities $P(w_i = -1) = P(w_i = 1) = \frac14$ and $P(w_i=0) = \frac12$, then the probability of $w$ lying in the kernel of $M$ is asyptotically (for large $n$) given by 
>   $$
> P(Mw=0) \sim 
> \begin{cases}
> \quad 2^{-n} \ , \quad m > \frac{2n}{\log_2 ( \pi n/6)} \\
> m^{-\frac12} \left( \frac{\pi n}6 \right)^{-\frac m2} \ , \quad m \leq \frac{2n}{\log_2 ( \pi n/6)} 
> \end{cases} \ . 
> \hspace{2cm} (1)
> $$

An intermediate step of this argument effectively supports an even stronger claim, namely that for *all* $m$
$$
P(Mw=0) - 2^{-n} \sim m^{-\frac12} \left( \frac{\pi n}6 \right)^{-\frac m2} \ . 
\hspace{2cm} (2)
$$
Since $w=0$  is always a solution of $Mw=0$ and has probability $P(w=0) = 2^{-n}$, the right hand side is essentially the asymptotic probability that $Mw=0$ with some $w \neq 0$. Consequently, since by definition every vector $w \in \{-1,0,1\}^n$ has at least probability $4^{-n}$, the probability that there exists at least one $w \neq 0$ with $Mw=0$ must then, with some suitable constant $\alpha>1$ and for large enough $n$, obey the following inequality: 
$$
P(\exists w \neq 0 : Mw=0) \leq \alpha \, 4^n m^{-\frac12} \left( \frac{\pi n}6 \right)^{-\frac m2} \ . 
\hspace{2cm} (3)
$$
Again, this supposes that $M$ is a random matrix, with uniform distribution over the set of all $m$ by $n$ $\{0,1\}$-matrices, or over the subset of Toeplitz matrices.

An adaptation of [the above argument](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207043/two-conjectures-about-zero-inner-products-and-dissociated-sets/229555#229555) to $\{-1,1\}$-matrices $M$ is completely straightforward; the eigenvalues of $MM^{\rm T}$ are just scaled by a factor of $4$ (i.e. they asymptotically tend now to $n$ instead of $\frac n4$) and the single large eigenvalue $\sim \frac{mn}4$ disappears. The above inequality $(3)$ then becomes instead 
$$
P(\exists w \neq 0 : Mw=0) \leq \alpha \, 4^n \left( \frac{2\pi n}3 \right)^{-\frac m2} \ . 
\hspace{2cm} (4)
$$
The base 2 logarithm of the expression on the right hand side is $\log_2\alpha + 2n - \frac m2 \log_2 \left( \frac{2\pi n}3 \right)$, and so for $m > \beta \frac{4n}{\log_2 ( 2\pi n/3)}$ (with some constant $\beta>1$ of our choice) it will be bounded from above by $\alpha \, 4^{(1-\beta)n}$ and thus become arbitrarily small for large enough $n$. Recall that this is an upper bound on the probability that *any randomly chosen* $m$ by $n$ matrix $M$ (of the required form) will admit a nontrivial solution $w \in \{-1,0,1\}^n$ of the equation $Mw=0$. For given $n$ and $m$ there is a number $2^{n+m-1} \gg 1$ of such matrices of Toeplitz type (or $2^{nm} \gg 1$ of general form), so the probability that every single one of these will admit such a nontrivial solution must become overwhelmingly small for large $n$.

> In conclusion, what the above argument tells us is that if we choose some $\beta>1$ and consider the $m$ by $n$ $\{-1,1\}$-matrices $M$, with sufficiently large $n$ and any $m$ obeying 
>   $$
> m > \beta \frac{4n}{\log_2 \left( \frac{2\pi n}3 \right)} \ , 
> \hspace{2cm} (5)
> $$
>   then with overwhelming probability there will be at least one among these matrices which has the wanted property (i.e. at least one $M$ which does *not* admit any nontrivial solution of $Mw=0$). This holds independently of whether we require in addition that $M$ has a Toeplitz, Hankel or circulant form. Moreover, not just one but probably the majority of all matrices of the specified form will have the wanted property.

Note that the condition $(5)$ is asymptotically weaker than $m>n/c$ for *any* real constant $c>1$, which implies that for any such $c$ and sufficiently large $n$ there should exist $n$ by $m$ Toeplitz (Hankel, ...) matrices with $m<n/c$ which have the wanted property. In the Question, $c=2$ was chosen.

*A final note:* Of course, in the present form the entire argument is not mathematically rigorous, since it relies on several uncontrolled approximations. I believe, however, that with a little effort these holes can be filled.

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment on Dierk Bormann's answer with roughly the same estimate.

The case $m< c\frac{n}{\log n}$ can be done using the pigeonhole principle.
For every vector $\mathbf{x}\in\{0,1\}^n$, take the $m$-vector $M\mathbf{x}$.

Every coordinate of $M\mathbf{x}$ is some integer in the interval $[-n,n]$. So there are $2^n$ choices for the vector $\mathbf{x}$, and at most $(2n+1)^m$ possible results for $M\mathbf{x}$. If $2^n>(2n+1)^m$ then there are some vectors $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in \{0,1\}^n$ such that 
$M\mathbf{x}=M\mathbf{y}$. Then $v=\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}$ satisfies the requred properties.

So a suitable vector $v$ exists if $2^n>(2n+1)^m$, or equivalently $m<\frac{n}{\log_2(2n+1)}$.

This works for all $m\times n$ matrices with entries from a fixed set of integers, so it does not use the special form of $M$.

---

Another approach is applying Minkowski's theorem. I did not have time to work it out for this case, it requires some unpleasant estimates, but it is clear to me that the same $m<c\frac{n}{\log n}$ can be achieved, and perhaps it is possible improve the estimate using the stucture of $M$.

The idea is as follows.
We need a vector $v$ from the kernel of $M$, such that every $v_i$ is an integer, lying in the interval $(-2,2)$.

The kernel $\mathrm{ker}\,M = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: Mx=0\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with dimension $d$; obviosly $d\ge n-m$.

The integer vectors in this subspace form a lattice. We need an upper bound on the $d$-volume of the lattice parallelepiped.

We need a suitable lower bound on the $d$-volume of the set 
$K = (-2,2)^n \cap \mathrm{ker}\,M$ which is convex and symmetric wrt. the origin.

If the ratio of the two volumes is high enoough, we can apply Minkowski's theorem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are arguing that there is a $c$ for which  $m< cn/\log{n}$ implies there must be a $v\in \{-1,0,1\}^n$ in the kernel.  This is in some sense the opposite of the original question right?

Comment: The question asks about solving $cn$ equations simultaneously. In my argument we have slightly fewer equations, so it does not answers the question at all.

Comment: I agree that the pigeonhole principle provides a simple proof of the fact that there is a constant $\alpha$ such that for $m<\alpha\frac{n}{\log n}$ any equation $Mv=0$ must have nontrivial integer solutions. However, the questions was under which conditions there exists an $M$ which admits *only* the trivial integer solution $v=0$. Surprisingly, it turns out that the criterion for this looks very similar, $m>\beta\frac{n}{\log n}$ with another constant $\beta$, again independently of whether Toeplitz, Hankel, or general $\{-1,1\}$-matrices are considered. But this is much harder to prove.

Comment: The same comment applies in my opinion to the suggestion to use Minkowski's theorem. Again, the existence of nontrivial solutions can perhaps be proved in this way, but not their absence.